# Problem with if statement

Tags: c

There was an example in my book where it was asked to write a program that prints the number 1 to 100 using 5 columns (Have each number separated from the next by a tab).
The solution was as following:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
 int i;

 for(i=1; i<=100; i++) {
  printf("%d\t", i);
  if((i%5)==0) printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}
```

But I can't understand the **if((i%5)==0) printf("\n");** statement. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: Note that the program given in the book cheats a little. Rather than separating each number from the next by a tab, it puts a tab after every number. So each line has an unnecessary tab on the end of it. You could try fixing that as an exercise.

Comment: `printf("%d%c", i,  ( i % 5 )  ? '\t' : '\n');` is so much more fun.

Answer (score 10):

The `%` operator is the modulus operator (integer division's remainder). So every five loop iterations, your program will output a `\n` character (new line).

Values will be:

```
Iteration         i%5 value
      i=1                 1
      i=2                 2
      i=3                 3
      i=4                 4
      i=5                 0
      i=6                 1
      i=7                 2
      i=8                 3
      i=9                 4
     i=10                 0
```

So, every five prints, a `\n` (new line) will be printed to the standard output.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In other words, the statement `x % y == 0` will be true when `x` is evenly divisible by `y` (that is, `x` is a multiple of `y`).  The technique of using `% y == 0` with a counter is an easy way of making something happen every `y` number of times through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The if condition checks if the number represented by `i` is divisible by 5 .

```
5 % 5 = 0 // remainder 
5 / 5 = 1  // quotient
```

Answer (score 0):

That means *if i is divided by 5 with no remainder new line character is printed*.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the modulo operator, which is the remainder after division. To expand it and make it easier to read,

```
if( (i%5) == 0 )
{
    printf("\n");
}
```

So, if the remainder of `i` divided by 5 is 0 (if `i` is evenly divisible by 5), print a newline. So, this will happen at `i` = 5, 10, 15, 20, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `i%5` returns the modulo (the remainder after division) of 5. So

```
1%5 = 1
2%5 = 2
3%5 = 3
4%5 = 4
5%5 = 0
6%5 = 1
etc...
```

Every 5th time through the loop the modulo is zero and a newline is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
6 % 5 = 1
.........
```

The % operator is called modulus, it returns the remainder of the first argument divided by the second argument.  Using it on the loop variable is a simple way to count every 5 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Your program prints the numbers 1 to 100, and when the number is divisible by 5, it goes to a new line. This way, it creates five columns (with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on top of the columns).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that shows more about the [modulus operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s2s80tk%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Realize it's used as a bit of a "trick" sometimes like above, although complelety valid and it's used "everywhere" like that.

By trick, I mean it's used to print something every 5 lines. :-)

Comment: Good Grief, in the time it took to type out my anwser, 6 new answers arrived.

Answer (score 0):

(i % 5) will be zero for every fifth time and '\n' will start printing from next line.
1'\t'2'\t'3'\t'4'\t'5'\n'
6.......